# Easiest way to convert two columns to Python dictionary

Tags: python

How would I put the following information into a Python dictionary -- http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html? Keys would be the country and values would be the two-character ISO code.

For example, I want the result to be:

```
mapping_of_country_to_iso = {'AALAND ISLANDS':'AX','AFGHANISTAN':'AF',...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just copied and pasted the important data into a text file called 'countries.txt' then did something like this:

```
import string

myFilename = "countries.txt"

myTuples = []


myFile = open (myFilename, 'r')

for line in myFile.readlines():
    splitLine = string.split (line)
    code = splitLine [-3]
    country = string.join(splitLine[:-3])
    myTuples.append(tuple([country, code]))

myDict = dict(myTuples)
print myDict
```

It's probably not the "best" way to do it, but it seems to work.

Here it is following John Machin's helpful recommendations:

```
import string

myFilename = "countries.txt"


myDict = {}

myFile = open (myFilename, 'r')

for line in myFile:
    splitLine = string.split (line)
    code = splitLine [-3]
    country = " ".join(splitLine[:-3])
    myDict[country] = code

print myDict
```

Comment: That is a pretty awesome/straightforward way to do it. Python's very powerful with strings.

Comment: I just paste it into the interpreter. I do that all the time with small data sets : ) `data = '''` + paste + `'''` - yes very powerful.

Comment: (1) You don't need `readlines`; `for line in myFile:` suffices. (2)`tuple([country, code]))` could be simplified to `(country, code)`. (3) Even better would be to whack them straight into the dict: initially `myDict = {}` and then `myDict[country] = code` each time around the loop (4) consider using `thing` always instead of `myThing` sometimes. HTH.

Comment: (5) Unless you're targeting Python 1.x, use `" ".join(seq)` instead of `string.join(seq)` ... most functions in the `string` module are deprecated in favour of `str` methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you're python2.7+, you can use dictionary comprehensions

```
{k:v for k,v in list_of_tuples}
```

where each member of the tuple is of the form `("AALAND ISLANDS", "AX")`. This is the more general solution but is probably not necessary for your scenario.

For older pythons, you can simply call the dictionary constructor with the list of tuples as an argument.

```
dict(list_of_tuples)
```

and you'll get what you want.

Comment: and how would I get the tuples?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe the `df.to_dict()` function will be most helpful.

Assuming your data frame of country information is called df, first (if it isn't already), set 'Country' to index. Next, use the `.to_dict()` function. Here's how the code should look:

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
dict = df.to_dict('series')
```

`'series'` is just one of the ways to organize the dictionary. I would recommend taking a look at the pandas documentation for [.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), as there are several ways to use this command.